# Cross process synchronization using EventWaitHandle in managed process and WaitForSingleObject in unmanaged process

Tags: c#

I have two processes, one created using C# and the other created using native C++.

I want to synchronize the two processes so that the unmanaged one will be blocked until the managed one is up and running.

In the managed process I have the following code:

```
// signal the unmanaged process that I am up and running
EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "MyEventName");
eventWaitHandle.Set();
```

In the unmanaged process I have the corresponding code to wait for the event

```
HANDLE hWaitEvent = CreateEventW(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, "MyEventName"); 
if (hWaitEvent)
{
    // wait for managed process to signal that it is up and running
    WaitForSingleObject(hWaitEvent, 5000);
}
```

As far as I can tell, after the event is set in the first process. The WaitForSingleObject in the other process fail to detect that and always waits until times-out.

Is there anything that I missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that does not work, you are creating an event on both ends.  One of them has to create it, the other has to open it.  OpenEvent() in the C++ code or EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting() in the C# code.  Whatever code starts first must create the event.

Comment: Thanks. Now I use HANDLE hWaitEvent = OpenEventW(NULL, TRUE, eventName);  to open the event. But the hWaitEvent is null. Do I need to specify the first parameter instead of NULL?

Comment: Use GetLastError().  Your arguments are pretty random, you need to ask for SYNCHRONIZE access.  If the two processes are in different sessions (like a service) then you need to prefix the event name with "Global\".

Answer (score 3):

What Hans Passant suggested was right, I needed SYNCHRONIZE access when open the event in C++.

Here is the code that worked:

In the managed process:

```
    EventWaitHandle _initializedEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, @"Global\Initialized");
```

In the native process:

```
    const WCHAR* initializedEventName = L"Global\\Initialized";
    int attempt = 0;
    HANDLE eventHandle = NULL;
    while ((eventHandle = OpenEventW(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, initializedEventName)) == NULL && attempt < 5)
    {
       Sleep(1000);
       ++attempt;
    }

    if (eventHandle != NULL)
    {
       WaitForSingleObject(eventHandle, 5000);
       CloseHandle(eventHandle);
    }
```